# Can I make my Mac's inet IP address static?

Tags: networking, macos, ip, port-forwarding, tunnel

I previously used Ngrok, then scrapped that for LocalTunnel for a short while before discovering CloudFlare Tunnel. All these services help me do the same thing, that is, expose local servers I use to help faciliate software development.

CloudFlare Tunnel provides a Docker daemon (Cloudflared) which I run locally. It communicates with my local development server and helps make that server accessible via the internet. I simply log into an admin panel via CloudFlare Zero Trust, then I enter my machine's INET IP. I assume the Docker daemon knows about this.

[image]

I get my INET IP by typing `ifconfig` in terminal.

[image]

I use the IP address in the en4 section beside `inet` in the image above. Everything works perfectly, but the IP address is dynamic, so I always need to log back into the admin panel mentioned above, then update the IP.

Is there a way to create a static IP that points to the en4 inet IP so that I can use that IP instead, kind of like what I think is referred to as IP aliasing?

Comment: does the IP that you covered up start with 10, 172.16, 192.168, or 169.254 ? they probably don't based on your description, but a necessary thing to establish.

Comment: Yep, it does. @FrankThomas. I was just reading about something called IP Aliasing. I was wondering if that could work. For example, using a static IP as an alias for the INET IP.

Comment: ok so that is weird. it implies that you are using a local (non public) IP address, but then it doesn't make sense why you would need to update that in the service config. can you describe the setting you need to modify? what is its label, and what are some of the other controls that are grouped with it? that said though, it sounds like you should be able to just set a static IP on the interface that is within the tunnels range. the choice to use or ignore DHCP auto-assignment is up to the individual device. no aliasing should be required. since they are non-pub IPs theres no reason to hide em

Comment: @FrankThomas I edited the post to provide some more information.

Comment: If you are talking about the IP address from your ISP, only your ISP can provide you with a static address. Many ISPs allow you to have a static address for a fee.

Comment: Are you connected via a router or direct via a modem?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek My router is connected to a fibre modem, and laptop is connected to the router using an ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a Static IP is something you need to work out with your ISP. Setting up a workstation with the external IP won't work through your ISP Modem.

If you have your Mac plugged directly into the modem (no other devices or router) then the IP is assigned by the ISP and you cannot change that.

Most times Static IP involves an upcharge (try to do this) or a business Plan.

Comment: What if my Mac is plugged into my router which is plugged into a modem?

Comment: That should work if the router is configured correctly. I do this routinely, But your static IP must be assigned by the ISP and that will be at the modem. Your Mac can have an internally assigned static IP